# How to configure external documentation in PyCharm for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I tried the following config string:

```
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/{module.name}.html?highlight={element.name}#sqlalchemy.{element.name}
```

Unfortunately PyCharm always opens http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/ instead of the correct module's page.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11115

Comment: @lhuang You are right. Thank you.
You can add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a PyCharm issue. Please check the following link for details.

[PY-11115 Adding External Documentation configuration does not work](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11115)